# Running Oven and Oven Fan is turning off while running without tripping the circuit breaker

Tags: oven, shutoff

Recently when running in conjunction with my microwave was causing my oven to "turn off" (this also impacted by oven fan AND one of my bathroom switches which is on the other side of my kitchen/oven.

This is was not impacting the other associated switches and lights which are on the same breaker so I moved the microwave to a different circuit/breaker but this oven turning off is still happening.

Any help with this issue would be appreciated.

I will try to run some troubleshooting to see what trigger this set of circuits to turn off so hopefully will have a better update but again any insight would be helpful.

Thank you!

Comment: What make and model is the malfunctioning oven please?

Comment: The micro is on a different circuit now—what about the switch you mentioned (I’m guessing a light or a fan)?

Comment: Is this a new- to- the- house oven? Wondering if your wiring is rated to match the amperage of the oven.... How many amps is the oven? To what size breaker is it connected to and controlled by?

Comment: the Model no.  GE - JGB600SET2SS (I have had this stove for 8+ years) and as noted above when this happens, the oven + oven fan (above the stove) and the vanity light switch and circuit all turn off in conjunction.  the fan is an Oven Fan so that can't be moved.  This is an older house (1950s) with the wiring has not been updated since it was built to my knowledge  the Oven is rated for 120W and the breaker as it indicates on the label is 15.  This house appears to have some very odd wiring (I'm not expert) so based on my observation.